# Can Oracle UCM Web Form store/retrieve data directly into/from database

Tags: oracle, forms, webforms, oracle-ucm

I have found several articles mentioning that using "UCM Web Forms" you can easily provide and interface for contributor to enter data in a specific format(split into specific fields).

In my case the data for some of the fields(e.g. drop-downs) have to be taken out from a database. And when the form is submitted it will be nice if the data is stored in the DB too, so is this possible with these web forms.

Also it will be great if someone can provide a link to a demo/tutorial/working example of using UCM Web Forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle UCM provides a mechanism to check in documents but no to manipulate directly database entries. You have to write your own code to manipulate the form/data or use a Java framework for this.

Answer (score 1):

http://blogs.oracle.com/kyle/entry/adding_ucm_web_forms_to_site_s

Gives an explanation and example.

Hopefully this helps whoever stumbles on this question.